# FancyHDR rightmark without numbers

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr

I'm trying to create a custom header for my twoside document. The header is supposed to display the section-header and the subsection-header in the format "section - subsection" without numbers. I got rid of the section-numbers, by redefining `\sectionmark` but can't figure out, how to get rid of the subsection numbers. I tried redefining `\chaptermark`, but it says that the command is not defined since I'm using the article class. Is there any other way to style `\rightmark` to get rid of the numbers or alternatively style `\leftmark` to show the section title and the subsection title (but both without numbers)?

```
\LoadClass[a4paper,11pt,twoside]{article}

\RequirePackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{ \markboth{#1}{} }
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\newcommand{\setHeaders}{
    \pagestyle{fancy}
    \fancyhf{}
    \fancyhead[EL]{\color{Black}\selectfont\bf\sffamily\nouppercase{\leftmark}}
    \fancyhead[ER]{\color{Black}\selectfont\bf\sffamily\nouppercase{\thepage}}
    \fancyhead[OR]{\color{Black}\selectfont\bf\sffamily\nouppercase{\leftmark}}
    \fancyhead[OL]{\color{Black}\selectfont\bf\sffamily\nouppercase{\thepage}}
    }
```

Comment: First, are you using \pagestyle{fancy}?  \subsectionamrk uses \markright, so \leftmark should only contain the section title.

Comment: In any case, use `\renewcommand*\subsectionmark[1]{\markright {#1}}`.

Comment: Thank you, that actually fixed my whole problem :)